# Monitoring multiple Linux Systems or Servers Script

Tags: linux, shell

I want to modify my script in such a way it can monitor my cpu, memory and ram on 4 servers on my network, the script below is a script that can monitor for one server, is there a way i can check or modify my script below if i have the hosts and username and password.

```
printf "Memory\t\tDisk\t\tCPU\n"
end=$((SECONDS+3600))
while [ $SECONDS -lt $end ]; do
MEMORY=$(free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf "%.2f%%\t\t", $3*100/$2 }')
DISK=$(df -h | awk '$NF=="/"{printf "%s\t\t", $4}')
CPU=$(top -bn1 | grep load | awk '{printf "%.2f%%\t\t\n", $(NF-2)}')
echo "$MEMORY$DISK$CPU"
sleep 5
done
```

any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Don't roll your own. There are much better monitoring tools out there pre-built, and they'll be lower-overhead than this (which runs... ten new processes, it looks like, every single polling cycle) as well as more featureful (able to maintain history in an efficient storage format, keep graphs, generat derivatives, alert on unexpected values, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple, naive implementation might look like:

```
for server in host1 host2 host3 host4; do
  ssh "$server" bash -s <<'EOF'
...your script here...
EOF
done
```

...with RSA keys preconfigured for passwordless authentication. That could be made *slightly* less naive by leveraging ControlMaster/ControlSocket functionality in ssh, so you're keeping the same transport up between multiple ssh sessions and reusing it wherever possible.

However -- rolling your own system monitoring tools is a fool's errand, at least until you've been around the block with the existing established ones, know their strengths, know their weaknesses, and can make a reasoned argument as to why they aren't a good fit for you. Use something off-the-shelf maintained by people who've been doing this for a while.